# Objective C - Writing an NSString to a plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, xcode

I'm writing an NSString to a plist file but after its written to the plist, and when I try to open i get the following message 
"This document "mylist.plist" could not be opened XML parser error: Unexpected character 2 at line 1 Old-style plist parser error: Unexpected';' or '=' after key at line 1"

Here is my code:

```
NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n Selection is %@ \n %d for %.2lf = %.2lf", [NSDate date], @"IPC", 2, 42.34, 2 * 42.34]; 
[temp writeToFile:[self getPathName:@"mylist.plist"] atomically:YES];
```

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-[NSString writeToFile...]` does not create a plist.  It creates a text file.  There is no such thing as "writing a string to a plist".  Only `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` objects can be written to plist files.  Those can then contain `NSString` objects (and other objects, like `NSDate` and `NSData`, etc), but what you're asking for is not possible.

For more information, check out the [Property List Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048-CJBGDEGD).

Edit:  I should clarify what I mean by "creating a plist".  When I say that, I'm referring to the XML documents defined by the Apple Plist DTD: http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd

Answer (score 0):

`%@\n Selection is %@ \n %d for %.2lf = %.2lf` is definitely *not* in any plist format. If you want to retain the plist format, use `+[NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:...]` to convert the string into data as a plist, then save the data.

And I don't see a reason to use plist if you're only storing 1 string. You can simply save as a .txt and load it using `+[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:...]`.